# Which philosophy does devi bhagavatam teach?

Tags: philosophy, devi-bhagavata-purana

There are different types of philosophies like Advaita, vishistadvaita, dvaita etc..

What kind of philosophy does devi bhagavatam teach? What is Devi's relationship with Brahman?

Comment: Does Puranas teach philosophy?I never heard of it!!

Comment: Guys !! Everything in Hinduism is NOT philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard that any Purana teaches any specific Philosophy. Its the commentators who interpret the words and bring some philosophy out of it.

Comment: Sometimes they will have dualistic nature verses sometimes non-dualistic .. Puranas in general are tilted towards dualism I think

Comment: @Rickross But the same Bhagavat has been used to teach Achintyabhedabhedabaad!

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee not devi bhagvatam but srimad bhagvatam whoch is vaishnava text

Comment: @RakeshJoshi yes i know that and meant that